# How to display to console nodes from linked list

Tags: javascript, debugging, linked-list, nodes, console.log

I have a class which creates a link list and also a function that adds nodes to that list . I am trying to implement more functions to the list but I want to see the changes these functions make by displaying the entire list .

this is the code :

```
function LinkedList() {
  var length = 0;
  var head = null;

  var Node = function(element) {
    this.element = element;
    this.next = null;
  };

  this.size = function() {
    return length;
  };

  this.head = function() {
    return head;
  };

  this.add = function(element) {
    var node = new Node(element);
    if (head === null) {
      head = node;
    } else {
      var currentNode = head;

      while (currentNode.next) {
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
      }

      currentNode.next = node;
    }
    length++;
  };
```

After declaring a LinkedList class and adding elements with the class.add(element) function , how can I display the entire list with console.log() ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the `toString` method of the LinkedList class. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString

Answer (score 0):

You could define a method `toString` in `prototype` object and loop through all the items.

```js
function LinkedList() {
  var length = 0;
  var head = null;

  var Node = function(element) {
    this.element = element;
    this.next = null;
  };

  this.size = function() {
    return length;
  };

  this.head = function() {
    return head;
  };

  this.add = function(element) {
    var node = new Node(element);
    if (head === null) {
      head = node;
    } else {
      var currentNode = head;

      while (currentNode.next) {
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
      }

      currentNode.next = node;
    }
    length++;
  };

}
LinkedList.prototype.toString = function() {
    let  head = this.head();
    let result = [];
    while(head) {
        result.push(head.element);
        console.log();
        head = head.next;
    }
    return result.join(", ");
}
let list = new LinkedList();
list.add("test");
list.add("test2");
list.add("test3");

console.log(list.toString());
```